# Что происходит с указателем на объект класса, если в конструкторе этого класса вызывается исключение?

Tags: c++, ооп, исключения

Существует класс val с единственным полем *a*. Конструктор этого класса бросает исключение, если значение поля == 0. Пусть указатель ptr указывает на динамически выделенную память для объекта класса val. Если в конструкторе класса выбросится исключение, то что же станет с указателем, выделится память или нет? Если да, то как её очистить в конце программы?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class val {
private:
    int a;
public:
    val(int _a): a(_a) {
        if (a==0)
            throw - 1;
    }
};
void main() {
    try {
        val* ptr = new val(0);
    }
    catch (int) {
        cout << "Error";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Память сразу же освобождается автоматически.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new

> If initialization terminates by throwing an exception (e.g. from the constructor), if new-expression allocated any storage, it calls the appropriate deallocation function